# Mule XStream XML to Object

Tags: java, xml, mule, xstream

I have this xml format that must be converted via Mule XML to Object component. Using xStream.

```
<server session="1234" time="2014-01-01T00:00:00">
    <getbalance id="101" guid="X9HK3G898NYML5B5" />
</server>
```

And the alias class

```
public class Server {   
    private String session;
    private Date time;
    // getters and setters
}
```

**mule xml**

```
...
<mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer doc:name="XML to Object">
    <mulexml:alias name="server" class="ps.Server"/>
</mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer>
...
```

when simulating the request i got null

```
Server [session=null, time=null]
```

how to get `session="1234" time="2014-01-01T00:00:00"` from the root node?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the server class like this

```
public class Server {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String session;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private Date time;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Hope it helps